# Get full powershell command from .net System.Management.Automation.PowerShell api

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Given is the following c# code based on System.Management.Automation.PowerShell. 
The concrete powershell command doesn't matter, it's just an example:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                shell.AddCommand("Import-Certificate")
                    .AddParameter("CertStoreLocation", @"cert:\CurrentUser\Root")
                    .AddParameter("FilePath", @"C:\Users\foo\GlauxSoftAISCertificateEIDAS.cer");

                var result = shell.Invoke();

                if (result.Count == 0)
                {
                    //ok
                }
                else
                {
                    //not ok
                }
            }
        }
```

This c# sample is the same as the following powershell command:

```
Import-Certificate -FilePath "C:\Users\foo\GlauxSoftAISCertificateEIDAS.cer" -CertStoreLocation cert:\CurrentUser\Root
```

Is it possible to get the full powershell command as a string from the PowerShell instance in c#?
I'm creating a GUI for creating/deleting certificate using System.Management.Automation.PowerShell but i would like to show the concrete powershell command to the user before it is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on [Avshalom's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62389605/712649), here's how to support pipelines and positional arguments correctly:

```cs
private static string GetPsCommand(PowerShell ps)
{
    string cmdText = string.Empty;
    for(int i = 0; i < ps.Commands.Commands.Count; i++)
    {
        var cmd = ps.Commands.Commands[i];
        cmdText += cmd.CommandText;
        foreach (var param in cmd.Parameters)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.Name))
                cmdText += " -" + param.Name + ":";

            cmdText += param.Value;
        }
        if(cmd.IsEndOfStatement || i + 1 == ps.Commands.Commands.Count)
          cmdText += Environment.NewLine;
        else
          cmdText += "|";
    }
    return cmdText;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an helper method like this:

For example this command:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-Process")
  .AddParameter("Name", "powershell_ise")
  .AddParameter("ComputerName", "Computer");
Console.WriteLine(GetPsCommand(ps));
```

Will result:

```
Get-Process -Name powershell_ise -ComputerName Computer
```

The helper method:

```
private static string GetPsCommand(PowerShell ps)
{
    string cmdText = string.Empty;
    foreach (var cmd in ps.Commands.Commands)
    {
        cmdText += cmd.CommandText;
        foreach (var param in cmd.Parameters)
        {
            cmdText += " -" + param.Name + " " + param.Value;
        }
    }
    return cmdText;
}
```

This is the idea, you can update/extend this depend on what you need...

Answer (score 0):

You can explore the PowerShell object easily by running the code inside a PowerShell terminal

```bsh
$shell = [PowerShell]::Create()
$shell.AddCommand("Get-ChildItem").AddParameter("Path", "C:\")
```

I can see my command, as well as the parameters in these properties on the object:

```bsh
$shell.Commands.Commands[0].CommandText
$shell.Commands.Commands[0].Parameters
```

Does not look at first glance like it has a build-in `ToString()` that will give you the command text, but at least you have the data. It should be fairly easy to construct the equivalent PowerShell command string from that.

Edit:

Maybe off-topic since you are working in C#, but here is how I would do it in pure Powershell

```bsh
$shell = [PowerShell]::Create()
[void]$shell.AddCommand("Import-Certificate").AddParameter("CertStoreLocation", "cert:\CurrentUser\Root").AddParameter("FilePath", "C:\Users\foo\GlauxSoftAISCertificateEIDAS.cer");
$commandText = $shell.Commands.Commands | % {
    "$($_.CommandText) " + ($_.Parameters | % {"-$($_.Name) `"$($_.Value)`""}) -join " "
}
$commandText
```